# How add custom formatting in response in API.AI?

Tags: api-ai

Using Google API AI, we have created

- Agent
- Intents

  - User Say (Hi)

    - Response
    - Response Text (Welcome, How are you?)

We need Response in html format like

`<b>Welcome</b>, How are you?`

In short, How I will apply HTML tags in Response

Answer (score 0):

API.AI default responses are simple text only.  To include formatted text you must use platform specific response.  For instance to add bold text with the Google Assistant integratiion:

1. Click the `+` in the responses and select `Google Assistant`
2. Click `Add Message content` and then `Simple Response`
3. Add the contents of your message and enclose your desired text in two `*` character (for your example `**Welcome**, How are you?`)

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

---

---

---

[image]

Comment: But this only works if you also use that integration (Google Assistant in this case) correct? My web-demo just displays the ** as normal text...

Comment: Dialogflow's web demo does not support rich (read: non-text) responses

Comment: @matthewayne if I want to have my own web UI and need some html tags to be dispalyed should I still use Google Assistant?